# Set Button's BG Color to ttransparent when mouse is hovered

Tags: vb.net

How can I change the background color of this button when I hover/click the button? Here's the image: 
http://i.minus.com/ib0pWwQBJ6nlW9.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
Private Sub button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub

Private Sub button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.button1.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub
```

**(Or)**

```
nextBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor=Color.Transparent
```

Take a look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32401/Transparent-Buttons-in-NET)

Answer (score 0):

much easier on web form load event

`oggetto` is the button in your case

```
dim oggetto as object 
oggetto.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='transparent'")
```

then place this to get back on mouse out

```
oggetto.Attributes.Add("onmouseout",this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;")
```